# Add UIScrollView programmatically in a ViewController that contains a smaller UIView with objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have an UIViewcontroller. I have a smaller UIVIew in this UIVIewController. Now i am trying to add an UIScrollView programmatically that should contain the smaller UIView so i can scroll the smaller view up and down. The smaller UIView  is already created using the interface builder of xcode. So now i use the following code to add the scrollView and then add the smaller View in the scrollView. The scrollView should have the same size in width as the smaller View.

```
self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.smallerView.frame.origin.x, self.smallerView.frame.origin.y, self.smallerView.frame.size.width, self.smallerView.frame.size.height)];

[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.smallerView.bounds.size.width, self.smallerView.bounds.size.height*1.2)];
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.smallerView];
    
[self.view addSubview:self.scrollView];
```

The weird thing is that the objects that are contained in the smaller UIView are not inside the bounds of the UIScrollView. What am i missing? Do i have to add constraints for the smaller UIView programmatically? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you use auto-layout for your main view? By default it is usualy turned on. Maybe it can help if you add
    >scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
before [self.view addSubview:self.smallerView];

Comment: Quick test... added a view with 3 labels as subviews in Storyboard / Interface Builder... constraints properly set... The code you posted works fine. You really need to provide complete details of what you're doing and ***exactly*** what's happening. *"objects that are contained in the smaller UIView are not inside the bounds of the UIScrollView"* ... what does that mean? Are the objects actually subviews of `smallerView`? Or are they just overlapping it? What constraints have you set for `smallerView` and its subviews?

Comment: Thanks for your answers i will try your suggestions!

Comment: Did you check that the small view is well positioned in scroll view. That could be the cause of what you see : object are well positioned in small view but small view is not well positioned which lead to object seem not well positioned in small view.